# UIEdgeInsets not working on System Images in TabBar

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbaritem, uiedgeinsets, sf-symbols

I am using XCode System Images (SF Symbols) for `UITabBarItem` Images.  I'd like to remove the `UITabBarItem` Title which I have done.  But also move the `UITabBarItem` Image down slightly.

In the past when I wasn't using System Images this would work fine using `UIEdgeInsets`.  However, this appears to have no effect on System Images.

### Code:

```
let imageConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .regular)
    let imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: -8, right: 0)

lazy var activityTabBarItem: UITabBarItem = {
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "stopwatch")?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(imageConfiguration)
        let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil,
                                      image: image,
                                      selectedImage: image)
        tabBarItem.imageInsets = imageInsets
        return tabBarItem
    }()
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Use withAlignmentRectInsets(_ alignmentInsets: UIEdgeInsets) on image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took me a while, but you can use the UIImage property **withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: CGFloat)**

example:

```
UIImage(systemName: "someName")?.withBaselineOffset(fromBottom: 6.0)
```

Took me a few hours, but I ran into this on my custom tabBarController in SwiftUI. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use - **withAlignmentRectInsets(_ alignmentInsets: UIEdgeInsets)** property of UIImage, to successfully set insets for SFSymbols. Following code in your cases:

```
image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
```

[Apple doc for withAlignmentRectInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624100-withalignmentrectinsets)